# Email Send Limit for individual subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud

can we set a limit on how many emails should a subscriber receive in SFMC
Example: A subscriber should not receive more than 5 emails in a week or month from the SFMC?

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward OOTB solution currently would be to leverage the [Einstein Engagement Frequency](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_eef.htm&type=5) feature. You could set a custom range and then use the Oversaturated Subscribers DE to leverage as a suppression source in your sends